# postgres ignore -> orWhereHas

Tags: postgresql, laravel, heroku, laravel-5

I Have 2 version app, one in local use MySQL and the other one is build in Heroku using PostgreSQL

The plan is to have search form that able to lookup data from different table

The table is books, writters, categories, and publishers

**Here the controller**

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $keyword = $request->input('keyword');





        // multiple query from different table
        $query = Book::where('judul','like','%'.$keyword.'%')
        ->orWhere('label','like','%'.$keyword.'%')
        ->orWhere('isbn','like','%'.$keyword.'%')
        ->orWhere('status', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%')
        ->orWhereHas('writter', function ($query) use ($keyword) {
            $query->where('nama_penulis', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%');
        })
        ->orWhereHas('category', function ($query) use ($keyword) {
            $query->where('nama_kategori', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%');
        })
        ->orWhereHas('publisher', function ($query) use ($keyword) {
            $query->where('nama_penerbit', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%');
        })
        ;




        $book_list = $query->paginate(5);
        $pagination = $book_list->appends($request->except('page'));
        $total_book = $book_list->total();
        return view('dashboards.index', compact('book_list', 'keyword', 'pagination', 'total_book', 'nama_penulis'));
    }
```

The form works like a charm on local (using my MySQL), but when I'm using Postgres the search form only able to fetch from books table.

I wonder what make postgres ignoring my code

Comment: Try to check the raw sql of your query. Add toSql() in the end of the query and check if you can identify something with raw SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

someone on the Laracast explain to me that The problem is from `like` which is **Case Sensitive** for the Postgres, thats why my code didnt work.

If you have same issue, i recommend you to use `ilike` to make POstgres insensitive.

or you can try the alternative way by `whereRaw` instead.